# C++ Inherit constructor and extend its functionality

Tags: c++, oop, constructor

I have a base class from which I want to inherit it's constructor, but I want to add more stuff for the constructor to do in the subclass. Specifically, I want to run a function at the end of the constructor like ExtraSetup(), which does some subclass related initialization. What is a good way to do this?

Here's a simplified example. I want the subclass's ExtraSetup() to run when I initialize a subclass object. Note that I don't necessarily want to use this "using Base::Base;" and virtual function. If there is a simpler way that's even better.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class Base {
    protected:
        int base_number_;
        
        virtual void ExtraSetup(){
            cout << "This should NOT run" << endl;
        }
        
    public:
        Base(int number){
            base_number_ = number;
            ExtraSetup();  
        }
};


class Sub : public Base {
    public:
        using Base::Base;
    private:
        int sub_number_;
        
        void ExtraSetup(){
            sub_number_ = 200;  // some random extra setup
            cout << "This should run" << endl;
        }
};


int main()
{
    Sub sub_object(100);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the question is unclear. Please show the code that has an issue or that does not work the way you expect.

Comment: Isn't what you are asking natural behavior of inherited classes? When you create an instance of the derived class, constructor of base class will be called first. So anything you put in derived class' constructor will be following it.

Comment: What you asked for is the basic mechanic of derivation. You don't inherit a constructor but you inherit a class whose the constructor is required to call it's parent constructor in its initialization list. [Here is an example of what you asked for](https://godbolt.org/z/x73zffxr1)

Comment: Moreover, if _"ExtraSetup()"_ is supposed to just do subclass members initialization, I would suggest you to remove this function and use the constructor's initialization list instead, it would be more efficient (except if your members initializations are not trivial).

Comment: Edit - added code example. @Fareanor in my real use case, the ExtraSetup() reads a csv file into a vector (loop), which is the subclass member. I guess it's not trivial, like just assigning a member directly.

Comment: never call a virtual function in a constructor.

Comment: @grigouille Thanks for the tip. Could you provide an alternative to achieve the desired behaviour?

Comment: @Beni In this case, _"ExtraSetup()"_ may be justified ^^ Look at the simple godbolt example I linked to my first comment, it should help you achieve what you're trying to do :)

Comment: @Fareanor Thanks! Yes this is mostly what I need. There was an answer that's now deleted with a similar method. The only issue is that I want to avoid defining arguments in the subclass for the base class constructor. I already defined those in the base class, so is there a way to avoid code duplication?

Answer (score 1):

You might inherit also from your "member" part:

```
class Base {
public:
    // Several constructors
    // We don't want to duplicate those in Derived class
    Base(int number);
    Base(int, int);
    Base(std::string);
};

class Member
{
protected:

    Member()
    {
       // some random extra setup
       std::cout << "This should run" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base, protected Member
{
public:
    int sub_number_ = 200; // If this kind of initialization is sufficient
                           // You might simply use it instead of inheritance
public:
    using Base::Base;
};
```

Comment: It's not just a simple initialization that I need. ExtraSetup() opens a csv file, reads values from it based on some logic, creates a vector<cv::Point> and then assigns it to the member variable of the subclass. Is it possible to do without inheriting from 2 classes?

Comment: `CsvData csvData = OpencsvFile(somePath);`?

Comment: Yes, that's probably the best solution in my situation. Thanks! Although, in terms of software design, I would prefer to run all of my initializations through the constructor of the class. I'm not very experienced though so maybe that's not such a good approach.

Comment: Those member initializations are done in constructor, (and at initialization), whereas you do an assignation (indirectly) in constructor body.